# How to Check all items in a QLlistWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a QListWidget with items that have a checkbox,
I want to iterate throiugh all of them and mark them checked, I tried this:

```
void ScaperDialog::CheckAll(void) {
    dbg_prnt << "inside " << __func__ <<std::endl;
    QListWidget *list = parentWidget()->findChild<QListWidget *>();
    if (!list)
        std::cerr << "No QListWidget found" << std::endl;

    QList<QListWidgetItem *> items = list->findChildren<QListWidgetItem *>();
    QList<QListWidgetItem *>::iterator i;
    for (i = items.begin();i != items.end(); i++) {
        dbg_prnt << (*i)->text.ToString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but get a compiler error:
**error: ‘i.QList::iterator::operator*()->QListWidgetItem::text’ does not have class type**
`dbg_prnt << (*i)->text.ToString() << std::endl;`
this obviously is only to print each element, to get it marked, I would do `(*i)->setChecked(true);` instead of printing it but I think this will give me the same error.

How do I get this rolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`QListWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html) are not [`QObject`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html)s so you can not access through [`findChildren()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) method, what you should use is the [`count()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#count-prop) and [`item()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#item) method of [`QListWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html):

```cpp
void ScaperDialog::CheckAll(void) {
    dbg_prnt << "inside " << __func__ <<std::endl;
    QListWidget *list = parentWidget()->findChild<QListWidget *>();
    if (!list)
        std::cerr << "No QListWidget found" << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i < list->count(); ++i){
        QListWidgetItem *it = list->item(i);
        dbg_prnt << it->text().toStdString() << std::endl;
        it->setFlags(it->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        it->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
    }
}
```